# Filtering query in Realm by NSDate throws NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: ios, swift, predicate, realm

I've looked everywhere, even hitting some dubious sites with virus warning messages that never goes away, and I can't figure this out.

I'm simply trying to filter `Results<T>` object by date:

```
let messages = realm.objects(RMChatMessage).filter("timestamp > \(date)) AND (timestamp <= \(to))"))
```

And whenever this line is run, it raises the following:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "timestamp > 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000"'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fba8c65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000011174ebb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   Foundation                          0x000000010ffb66bd _qfqp2_performParsing + 8495
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010ffb4526 +[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:arguments:] + 46
...
```

I tried using `NSDateFormatter` with formats like `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss`, or `date.description`, using `NSPredicate(format:...)` instead of `Result<T>.filter(...)`, and so on, yet nothing worked.

Is this some bug in Realm?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`let messages = realm.objects(RMChatMessage).filter("timestamp > %@ AND timestamp <= %@", date, to)`

`NSPredicate` does not have any special handling for Swift string interpolation and doesn't support writing dates directly within the format string.

Comment: This worked.. So `NSPredicate` requires us to use Objective-C's format string syntax... weird. But thanks!