# How to query for String AND NSDate property?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am facing an odd error with my code:

```
if let date = self.messages.last?.date {
    let newMessages = self.realm.objects(Message).filter("chatId == '\(self.chatId!)' AND date > \(date)")
}
```

This outputs the error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "chatId = 'oSgUGWH9fWURmBh5NQZK2POpxdI3yEdl7PrPzAU33l7cVFIpzR38otF3' AND date > 2016-07-17 10:56:07 +0000"'

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

Using `NSPredicate` it works:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "chatId = %@ AND date > %@", self.chatId!, date)
newMessages = self.realm.objects(Message).filter(predicate)
```

But why doesn't the first solution work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering query in Realm by NSDate throws NSInvalidArgumentException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31952669/filtering-query-in-realm-by-nsdate-throws-nsinvalidargumentexception)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to filter an array using a predicate, you need to pass a predicate and not just a string literal as the argument, and also use the method `filteredArrayUsingPredicate(_:)`.

Why `"chatId == '\(self.chatId!)' AND date > \(date)"` doesn't work is that the compiler interprets this as a string literal - and not a predicate as you've created in your other example:

> ```
> NSPredicate(format: "chatId = %@ AND date > %@", self.chatId!, date)
> ```

The fix is to either instantiate an `NSPredicate` as you've done in your edit, and pass that value to `filteredArrayUsingPredicate(:_)` or just move the instantiation to inside the method:

```
newMessages = self.realm.objects(Message).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(NSPredicate(format: "chatId = %@ AND date > %@", self.chatId!, date))
```

If you want to use this method, the array needs to be an `NSArray`, and the objects in the array need to be KVC compliant, so you're better off in Swift with using the `filter(_:)` method as such:

```
let newMessages = self.realm.objects(Message).filter({ $0.chatId == self.chatId! && $0.date.compare(date) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending })
```

Comment: So the first method only works for `Strings`? But why does `filter("chatId == '\(self.chatId!)' AND age > \(age)")` with `age: Int` work?

Comment: I'll try to find a credible source for this, but I believe the reason is that `NSDate` doesn't conform to the `Comparable` protocol whereas `String` and `Int`, among others, do.

Comment: NSPredicate doesn't have any syntax for literal dates in format strings, while it does support literal numbers.